# JavaScript function onhover in <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I have got this code in HTML:

```
<div id="choice" onHover="npcRoll()">
    <p>Choose your weapon!</p>
    <button id="rock" onClick="choose(1)">Rock</button>
    <button id="paper" onClick="choose(2)">Paper</button>
    <button id="scissors" onClick="choose(3)">Scissors</button>
    <p>You chose <span id="userChoice"></span>!</p>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript code for it:

```
// Random
var random = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};  

// NPC
var npc;
function npcRoll(){
    npc = random(1, 3);
}
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
#choice {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 350px;
}
```

The idea was to make roll NPC number every time the user hovers over the `<div>` but it doesn't work. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no `onHover` event, use [`onmouseover`](http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0102/0102-ONMOUSE.html):

```
<div id="choice" onmouseover="npcRoll()">
```